# How to solve log4j2 CVE (CVE-2021-44228) issues for application under JBoss 7.x

Tags: jboss, log4j, log4j2, cve

I've some issues in porting some application running in a JBoss 7.1 environment from log4j to log4j2.

I've ported my SW to log4j2 (2.17.1), but that is not enough. I'm understanding that JBoss configuration changes - not so simple - are needed to obtain the applications run correctly and write log-data on the correct log-files.

Have you some hints to aid me?

Based on what I read on [the Redhat portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6577421) [customer access only] I wonder if a port for front-end applications is necessary.

> No version of JBoss EAP 6.x/7.x is vulnerable to CVE-2021-44228
> currently thanks to the usage of JBoss Logging framework instead of
> Log4J. Please refer to the security bulletin - RHSB-2021-009 for
> further information on this vulnerability and impacted Red Hat
> products. [...]  EAP 7.x's log manager does port in log4j JMSAppender
> code so is similarly impacted by CVE-2021-4104 with enabled
> JMSAppenders. But in further reviewing this vulnerability, we have
> determined this can only be considered a true vulnerability when the
> attacker has write access to the Log4j configuration to add a
> JMSAppender to the attacker's JMS Broker.

Comment: As I understand it, the Log4J vuln could be made safe without upgrading it, by turning off a facility that could pull in remote code (and thus perform a remote code execution). If you have found that you are running a vulnerable library, could you just throw this switch?

Comment: The switch should be something like {nolookup} in the correct line of the JBoss log conf file. But I would like to understand if I may act in other ways to make the best choice. I was asked not to change the JBoss configurations; a request, the latter, certainly impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7.1 is not vulnerable or affected by this CVE. This version of JBoss EAP does not include log4j 2. JBoss EAP 7.4 does include the log4j-api, but does not include log4j-core and therefore it is also not vulnerable.

In short JBoss EAP is not vulnerable and there is nothing in its configuration you need to change.

Comment: From your answer I understand that it isn't necessary to change the configuration of JBoss 7.1 EAP. I wonder if the applications and servlets that run under JBoss but which include in log4j.jar (version 1.x) are instead at risk of various CVEs. At this point I think it is best to port all applications and servlets to use common-logging and leave the use of log4j via JBoss. I err?

Comment: I don’t recall exactly, but I don’t think any components in JBoss EAP use log4j. If they do they definitely do not configure the log manager nor use any specific appenders. I do think it’s a good idea to use a logging facade like SLF4J or jboss-logging. However, using log4j loggers is safe. It’s configuring appenders that exposes the CVE’s.